# Access UI (controlsource property) vs VBA Performance

Tags: performance, vba, ms-access

Is there a difference in performance (speed, memory used, etc.)  when using the Access UI and setting a property to add a value to a textbox (or other control) as opposed to using VBA to do the same thing when object variables are correctly used?

For example, let's say that I want to select an item from a listbox and add values from the selected record to 2 textbox controls. I can do this by using the following VBA code in the `AfterUpdate` event procedure of the listbox:

```
Private Sub lstTest_AfterUpdate()
Dim lstA As Control

Set lstA = Me.lstTest

Me.txtTest1 = lstA.Column(0)
Me.txtTest2 = lstA.Column(1)

Set lstA = Nothing

End Sub
```

I can also set the ControlSource property using the MS Access UI via the Properties window in the txtTest1 and txtTest2 controls to the following to achieve the same result.

txtTest1 ControlSource: `=[lstTest].[Column](0)`

txtTest2 ControlSource: `=[lstTest].[Column](1)`

Is there any difference between these 2 approaches as far as performance is concerned? Any documentation on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a “bit” of difference, but not really anything that going to make or break the application performance wise.

The first example could be considered better, since the values are “stuffed” into the other controls. The problem of course is next time you load the form, if txtTest1/2 are UNBOUND then next time the form loads, you would presumably have to run some code to re-load up the values again. (so this makes the first example worse)

Thus in your first case, the values will NOT persist and next time you load the form (or navigate to a different record), then such values will not update since your first example ONLY updates the values WHEN the after update event fires. That after update event ONLY fires WHEN you change the combo box, not on a general form load or navigate.

So the issue likely not performance, but simply that of your first example will NOT work nor display the data next time the form loads (unless of course the textboxes were bound to underlying columns).

Since the code is required to always run when the form loads, or record navigation occurs, you likely best use the control source approach since in BOTH cases you likely want these values to display correctly and thus in both cases you have to reference the .column() property anyway.

Comment: That makes sense, I was mostly just curious on any minor differences between the two approaches. I generally prefer utilizing the Access UI whenever possible and when testing it, it appeared that the Control Source approach may have been more efficient but it's hard to tell. Thanks!

Comment: One caveat, it seems, to using the Control Source approach is that if you are using an INSERT SQL string to edit a record then you must use the AfterUpdate event or it will not allow the user to edit the data.